# Ansible Expect module can't match string/regex script questions

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm trying to automate a script installation through Ansible in a Vagrant machine.
I tried a lot to find a solution across the web but the documentation and the examples are very weak.

That script I'm trying to install is prompting questions that I'm trying to answer programmatically with the **Ansible Expect Module**.

Ansible Task:
- name: "Running Lisk installation"
    become: True
    become_user: vagrant
    expect:
        command: bash installLisk.sh install -r {{env}}
          responses:
                    'Where do you want to install Lisk to? (Default /home/vagrant)': "/home/vagrant"
            'Would like to install NTP? (y/n):': "y"
              echo: yes

It seems it can't recognize the question or the answer, **this is the error I'm getting back** from the provisioning
TASK [lisk : Running Lisk installation] ****************************************
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {
"changed": true,
"cmd": "bash installLisk.sh install -r test",
"delta": "0:00:30.137468", 
"end": "2016-08-26 08:18:46.740017",
"failed": true,
"rc": null,
"start": "2016-08-26 08:18:16.602549",

"stdout": "Checking prerequisites:\r\n
Curl is installed.\t\t\t\t\t\u001b[32mPassed\u001b(B\u001b[m\r\n
Tar is installed.\t\t\t\t\t\u001b[32mPassed\u001b(B\u001b[m\r\n
Wget is installed.\t\t\t\t\t\u001b[32mPassed\u001b(B\u001b[m\r\n
Sudo is installed and authenticated.\t\t\t\u001b[32mPassed\u001b(B\u001b[m\r\n\
u001b[32mAll preqrequisites passed!\u001b(B\u001b[m\r\n
Where do you want to install Lisk to? (Default /home/vagrant): ",

"stdout_lines": [
"Checking prerequisites:", 
"Curl is installed.\t\t\t\t\t\u001b[32mPassed\u001b(B\u001b[m", 
"Tar is installed.\t\t\t\t\t\u001b[32mPassed\u001b(B\u001b[m", 
"Wget is installed.\t\t\t\t\t\u001b[32mPassed\u001b(B\u001b[m", 
"Sudo is installed and authenticated.\t\t\t\u001b[32mPassed\u001b(B\u001b[m",
 
"\u001b[32mAll preqrequisites passed!\u001b(B\u001b[m", 
"Where do you want to install Lisk to? (Default /home/vagrant): "
]}
**Thank you** all guys in advance

Answer (score 4):

Responses in `expect` module are regular expressions, so question marks have special meanings.
You can simply use:

```
- expect:
    command: bash installLisk.sh install -r {{env}}
    responses:
      'install Lisk to': '/home/vagrant'
      'install NTP': 'y'
    echo: yes
```

Comment: Thank you so much it seems to work. Now It fails for an other problem that I'm trying to understand if you would like to try it I'm working on a public repository :) https://github.com/txchain/lisk-ansible

Comment: I resolved last issue giving to the expect task a large timeout according to the documentation http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html